# Linq to Object Lambda Expression Re-use

Tags: lambda

I have the following simple switch statement. As you can see, the expressions for Any are almost identical.

My question is:

1. Is there any way to re-use the expression so that I don't have to
   repeat it every time I need the same or similar expression.
2. if not possible to re-use the whole expression in Any, is it
   possible to re-use "x => x.Question == _question.Question" at least?

Thanks!

```
switch (_question.DataField)
                {
                    case DataField.FormData:
                    result = Report.ReportDataItems.Any(
                                                  x => x.Question == _question.Question
                                                  && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FormData)) && Int32.TryParse(x.FormData, out tempVal));
                        break;
                    case DataField.FormData2:
                    result = Report.ReportDataItems.Any(
                                                  x => x.Question == _question.Question
                                                  && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FormData2)) && Int32.TryParse(x.FormData2, out tempVal));
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: What is the type of your ReportDataItems?

Comment: Is this Linq to Objects or some other form of Linq?

Comment: Yes, Linq to Objects. ReportDateItems is of a custom type that has a number properties such as Question, FormData, FormData2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming in memory Linq 2 Objects, you can use a `Func` to extract the correct field and reuse the rest of the query; (calling the type of ReportDataItems `Item`here)

```cs
        Func<Item, string> fn;
        switch (_question.DataField)
        {
            case DataField.FormData:
                fn = x => x.FormData;
                break;
            case DataField.FormData2:
                fn = x => x.FormData2;
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        result = Report.ReportDataItems.Any(
                                      x => x.Question == _question.Question
                                      && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fn(x))) 
                                      &&  Int32.TryParse(fn(x), out tempVal));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick but working answer, Joachim! One follow-up question: what do I need to do if I want to build a function to return the fn? Thanks again.

Comment: @John Just make the function return a Func<Item, string> and return the correct lambda, a'la `private Func<Item, string> GetFun(DataField df) { if(df==DataField.FormData) return x => x.FormData; ...`

Comment: I tried the method you suggested with one difference. Instead of the Datafield parameter, I needed to Question (my custom type that has a enum property called DataField). Everything else is the same what you first suggested. But I got an ArgumentType is not assignable to parameter type "string". Does the "string" here refer to the second parameter in the return type? I know the "x" refers to Item that is of my custom type ReportDataItem but I do not see where it is passed into the function GetFun(). Sorry I am very new to the System.Func()  delegate.

Comment: @John The function `GetFun()` in my comment above actually _returns a function_ that takes an Item and returns a string. The item is passed in later (the `x` in `fn(x)` in the Linq expression) so it's not needed inside `GetFun()`. Hard to explain in a comment without seeing the complete context, you may want to ask a new question with your problem.